# Seaborn does not show all the numbers in the cells for confusion matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The function that I am using for plotting the confusion matrix is :

```
def plotConfMatrix(title,cm):
    sb.set(font_scale=1.4)
    cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm,columns= cm.keys(),index=cm.keys())
    #cm_df.index.name = 'Predicted'
    #cm_df.columns.name = 'Actual'
    sb.heatmap(cm_df, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16},fmt='d')
    plt.xlabel('Actual labels')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted labels') 
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix for ' + title)
    plt.show()
```

where in this function, the confusion_matrix is input as dict object and is converted to dataframe. But it shows value in only one of the cells. I tried upgrading the seaborn version still no success.  Dict object is :

```
{0: {0: 36, 1: 9}, 1: {0: 6, 1: 29}}
```

and DataFrame that it converts to is :

```
    0   1
0  36   6
1   9  29
```

Plot is :

[image: Confusion matrix]

What could be the probable issue? Also, I am using Python Idle editor and normal python shell in Ubuntu terminal to execute this code.

Comment: I could not duplicate the issue with your code in Jupyter Notebook. Seaborn Version 0.9.0

Comment: @Scott Boston am using python idle and python shell in normal ubuntu terminal where I am running this

Comment: maybe try adding a color to the `annot_kws`?

Comment: @Tacratis : how do we do that ?

Comment: [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wWmk.png) how it looks like when I run the code. Maybe update seaborn?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I already mentioned that but no success

Comment: I mean you obviously do not use the newest version. So did something go wrong when updating?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : it showed the same results even on updating

Comment: `print(seaborn.__version__)`, what does that show?

Comment: `annot_kws={'size'=16,'color':'b'}` gives me blue, you can specify whatever color you want (and size ofc). This is a low-tech solution, but if it works, it might be worth a try

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ; it was not taking the updated version, it worked now!